# Post viewmodel with List<T> to controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I know there are a lot of posts out there regarding this, most of which I have read and tried all morning but still can't get it working.

I have a view model as such:

```
namespace GrantTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class CoverPageViewModel
    {
        public List<Compliance> Compliances { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a partial view that uses the view model:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<GrantTracker.ViewModels.CoverPageViewModel>" %>

<%
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Compliances.Count; i++)
{ %>               
        <%=Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Compliances[i].ComplianceId) %>
        <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Compliances[i].ComplianceName) %>                 

<% } %>
```

This properly displays the text boxes and their values:

[image]

The generated source looks ok to me:

```
<input id="Compliances_0__ComplianceId" name="Compliances[0].ComplianceId" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="Compliances_0__ComplianceName" name="Compliances[0].ComplianceName" type="text" value="Human Subjects" />                 

<input id="Compliances_1__ComplianceId" name="Compliances[1].ComplianceId" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="Compliances_1__ComplianceName" name="Compliances[1].ComplianceName" type="text" value="Vertebrate Animals" />                 

<input id="Compliances_2__ComplianceId" name="Compliances[2].ComplianceId" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input id="Compliances_2__ComplianceName" name="Compliances[2].ComplianceName" type="text" value="Hazardous Substances" />
```

When I submit the page the textbox properties are as far as I can tell properly posted:

```
Compliances[0].ComplianceId:1
Compliances[0].ComplianceName:Human Subjects
Compliances[1].ComplianceId:2
Compliances[1].ComplianceName:Vertebrate Animals
Compliances[2].ComplianceId:3
Compliances[2].ComplianceName:Hazardous Substances
```

However, the values are all gone when accessed in the controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCoverPage(CoverPageViewModel coverPageViewModel)
{
    return Content(coverPageViewModel.Compliances[0].ComplianceId.ToString());
}
```

The debugger shows that it knows it should contain three Compliance objects.
However, when drilled down none of them have their values:

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I am really stuck on this.

Comment: can you show complete view?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Sure, I put it up here: http://pastebin.com/vWNuNMCn
Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: where is that partial view in which you have form and iterating on controls

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  THe partial view is described above in the question.  It does not have its own form post because it is nested in the form post of the full view.  It is called like this in the full view:             <% Html.RenderPartial("ComplianceControl", Model); %>

Comment: Can you show your `Compliances` class.

Comment: @Saranga Sure, there is not much to it:  http://pastebin.com/qXgSWMsq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Compliance` class as below.

```
public class Compliance
{
    public int ComplianceId { get; set; }
    public string ComplianceName { get; set; }
}
```

You should define properties correctly.

Comment: You nailed it! I feel like a real dunce for forgetting to include the getter/setters on the model object properties.  Thank you so much for helping me with this!